# Connecting two controllers AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers at different application levels. I want connect thew to connect them using factory. And have common model.

AngularJS:

```
    App.controller("searchCtrl",function(searcResultFactory){
        var vm = this;
        searcResultFactory.setRequest("some data");
    });

    App.controller("resultCtrl",function(searcResultFactory){
        var vm = this;
        vm.result = searcResultFactory.getRequest();
    });

    App.factory("searcResultFactory",function(){
        var _rqst = "";
        return {
            setRequest:function(rqst){
                _rqst = rqst;
            },
            getRequest:function(){
                return _rqst;
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use Services if you want to share data based on some request:

```
 App.service("searcResultFactory",function(){
        this._rqst = "";

            this.setRequest:function(rqst){
                this._rqst = rqst;
            }
            this.getRequest:function(){
                return this._rqst;
            }

    })
```